# MWAA uninstall python packages

Tags: airflow, mwaa

When we need to extend Airflow functionality in AWS MWAA then we just list
needed python packages in the requirements.txt file associated with the MWAA instance. MWAA installs them on its own.
But how can we remove some of the previously installed packages? Just removing them from the requirements.txt doesn't make MWAA uninstall them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload a blank requirements.txt file and re update the environment.

```
Can I remove a plugins.zip or requirements.txt from an environment?
Currently, there is no way to remove a plugins.zip or requirements.txt from an environment once they’ve been added, but we're working on the issue. In the interim, a workaround is to point to an empty text or zip file, respectively. To learn more, see Deleting files on Amazon S3.
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-faqs.html